# Calling multiple ajax files vs single one

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to know which is a better practice sending ajax request to multiple different files or sending to only one and passing a parameter to decide which method to call.

So for example:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'get_first_name.php'
});

$.ajax({
url: 'get_last_name.php'
});
```

VS

```
$.ajax({
url: 'get_user_data.php',
data: 'choose ' : 'first_name'
});
```

and in the php file we pass a method depending on the parameter we got
so we call

```
$user->get_first_name();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single file would be a better idea as you may re-use methods to format the output etc and internally you can call different classes and methods for different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is bad practice per se if you have a reason for breaking out the functionality into separate files. If you need both functions to complete before continuing, you may want to consider using promises and `$.when()` like so:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax('get_first_name.php');
    $.ajax('get_last_name.php');
).then(function (result1, result2) {
    // Handle results here
});
```

This allows you to handle multiple ajax calls without having to nest further ajax calls within success callbacks. This may only benefit you if you need both calls to complete before continuing forward, so it's possible this may not buy you any benefit.